# Add rule to filter multiple from addresses in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, mail-rule

We are using Outlook 2010. We want to add filter to move some mails from particular mail id to one folder. Any option in Outlook 2010 to add more than one "from" address to same rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a rule from selecting an existing email.

1. Click on `Advanced Options` on the `Create Rule` dialog.
2. On from condition click on the link.
3. Add additional names.

If creating a rule from `Rules and Alerts` dialog

1. Click on `New Rule`
2. Select a rule.
3. In `Rules Wizard` make sure the `from` condition is checked
4. Select the `people or public group` link from Step 2 section
5. Select multiple people.

Comment: This adds them with "OR". Is there an option for "AND"?