# Creating an Outlook rule that matches one or more senders

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

Our company recently made some changes to our email service. As a result, I need to recreate some email rules, but I am struggling to get them to work. I need a rule that will move an email to a folder if the sender matches any one of a list of possible addresses. I tried creating a rule like this:

> From is: foo@bar.com, foo-dev@barcom, blah@bar.com

but when I run the rule it has no effect. It works if I use only a single sender, so I'm assuming it is treating the list of senders like an AND statement. I could create a separate rule for each potential sender, but that is going to take a lot of time. I tried the suggestions here: [Add rule to filter multiple from addresses in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/579788/add-rule-to-filter-multiple-from-addresses-in-outlook-2010) but with no success.

Is there any way to create the rule I want in Outlook or am I stuck with one rule per sender?

Comment: How exactly did you create this rule? IIRC, the rule editor opens a list editor for sender address filters. Each entry must be on its own line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add rule to filter multiple from addresses in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/579788/add-rule-to-filter-multiple-from-addresses-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: @ harrymc unfortunately no. The steps described there are what I'm already doing.

Comment: @ Daniel B I'm using the MacOS client so the interface is a bit different. When I poent the dialog to create a new rule, I get a label that says "when a rule meets all these conditions" and a single line with dropdowns. I choose 'from', 'is', and then add the sender addresses.

Comment: Try separating the addresses using a semicolon in the way described in the 'UPDATE" section of this answer: https://superuser.com/a/405564/1007040 see if that works.

Comment: @ Blind Spots I suspect that answer is for an older version of Outlook. None of the interface feature they describe line up with the rules window. There is no hyperlink in the 'from' section and no way I can see to add semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to create a rule as shown in the below image in Outlook for Mac?

[image]

If so, please create a rule as following:

[image]

In this way, emails from any of these three people will be moved to the specific folder.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.